# How to catch URL from tab which autocloses?

Tags: browser

I am not sure how it works from the frontend part but there are some cases when buttons on the websites opens some tab and then closes it immediately (e.g. when downloading something). The button on the website doesn't have "copy link" option, browser network console doesn't catch it because it is technically new tab and browser history doesn't save that url.

Is there any in-browser way to catch such URLs? I have only external ideas like wireshark or video capture...